# Geometry of Banach Space (Radon Nikodym)

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, reference-request, banach-spaces, radon-nikodym

I read in David Williams, Probability with martingale : "The right context for appreciating the close inter-relations between martingale convergence, conditional expectation, the Radon-Nikodym theorem, ect. is the geometry of Banach Spaces."

Does anyone have a introduction to this topics please ? I'm curious to see what's th meaning of that !

Have a good day!

Comment: If you are new to Geometry of Banach Spaces an excellent place to start with is Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at this, my for my project for the next semester.